# How to copy list with two different generic types?

Tags: java, list, collections

i have in one class the follwoing code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(objType.getParameters());
```

To copy a list into a list you can simply do like this : `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(objType.getParameters());`

But this is if the `objType.getParameters()` List is of a String. now in my case its not so but its a Parameter object.

```
public class Object_type {

    public String object_type;
    public Property properties;
    private List<Parameter> parameters;
    public List<Restriction> restriction;

    public List<Parameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

}
```

And my parameter class is just a struct with Strings and Integers.

```
public class Parameter {

    String parameter;
    String data_type;
    String description;
    int min_no;
    int max_no;
    int order1;
    int nested;
    String default1;
    String format;

}
```

I have a `List<String>` that must be like that and a `List<Parameter>` That must be like that
So how can I copy my list into my like in this case?.
Collection.copy is not working neither.

```
// Create a list of node and compile the xpath expression
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(
                    xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            arr = new String[nodeList.getLength()][constants.getParamColumns().length];

            // Loop thru the list and add to string array.
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength()
                    / constants.getParamColumns().length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < constants.getParamColumns().length; j++) {

                    arr[i][j] = nodeList.item(
                            j + (i * constants.getParamColumns().length))
                            .getTextContent();

                    list.add(nodeList.item(
                            j + (i * constants.getParamColumns().length))
                            .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("current size in list : " + list.size());
                }
            }
            setArr(arr);


                        Add list to List<Parameter> here <-----
            System.out.println(" size of list : "
                    + objType.getParameters().size());
```

Comment: Try to describe exact problem you are trying to solve, not a solution you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a nodeList of String coming from xml parsing that I wanna get into a List of <Paramater> into to my struct class

Comment: Just write a code which parses list of strings and creates `Parameter` objects, there is no magic here, just do it as is.

Comment: ok here my updated code so you will understand my problem more.

Comment: Do not create `List<String>`, just create `new Parameter` and assign its fields from xml nodes. Then add the `Parameter` instance to the `List<Parameter>`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The same as you cannot assign one incompatible type variable to another, e.g. "String s = new Parameter()".

Comment: Yes, It seem so but how can I then solve this problem?

Comment: @Sembrano The problem "assigning one type to another incompatible type" is not solvable, state your exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannnot assign paramerters to String. Need to change the type of List

```
List<Parameter > list=objType.getParameters(); //UPDATED
```

Comment: Can do this directly -- *List<Parameter > list=objType.getParameters();*

Comment: @gowtham oh yes. Apologies for not looking at the complete code

Comment: No you cannot do like that

Comment: @Sembrano yes yes your requirement doesn't suite this, you have to iterate the node values , create a parameter object and add that to the list.

Comment: @Sembrano why not? what kind of list are you trying to generate. If you want to generate some string representation and you need to iterate over the list and add string representation of the parameter object to the list

Answer (score 0):

Doing it pretty Vaguely,
You can iterate over list of String that you get and manually create the Parameter object by manipulating the String received and then add Parameter object into the List of Parameters.

It will work only if you can manipulate the received String and identify exactly which information you want into your Parameter Object.

Hope this helps!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thats the problem I dont know my info. Its coming depeing on user selction. I updated my code.